# How can I understand "remnant movement" in English heavy-NP shift construction

Tags: syntax, english, grammar, generative-grammar, movement

Kayne 2003 mentions that there exists *remnant movement* in English. As background, note:

> I predicted that John would marry Susan, and marry Susan/her/*Ann he will.

The argument(s) in the preposed VP must not be ‘new information.’ That is why in this sentence, *Ann* is starred. But it is not the case with *Susan* or *her* because *Susan* and *the pronoun* denote old information.

Kayne finds the following sentence acceptable:

> I predicted that John would marry Susan, and marry he will the woman he loves.

Thus, it is an instance of remnant VP-movement.  The ‘heavy’ NP/DP *the woman he loves* has been moved out of the VP before the VP is fronted.

The derivation of the sentence will look like

[image]

Any type of comment is welcome! In my view, the notion of "remnant movement" is very confusing to me. Is there any better solution or explanation? Or another simplified hypothesis? Thanks very much beforehand!

Comment: I find Kayne's sentence rather marginal. I had to read it twice to get the processing correct. I am therefore skeptical about the validity of his analysis.

Comment: and marry Susan he will OR and marry her he will.  Yes, Ann is new information. Susan and her are anaphoric.

Comment: And this: I predicted that John would marry Susan, and marry he will the woman he loves. is OK.

Comment: _... and marry he will the woman I predicted_. But that opens up a lot of opportunities: _and marry he will the woman that I predicted Jane would tell Alena was perfect for him, except for her feet._ How much of this information is "new" and how much can it contribute to grammaticality (not to mention reference)?

Comment: @jlawler I am not sure. Sometimes the "old/new information" doesn't hold for many cases. I am suspicious of the statement.

Comment: thanks for all the comments! I guess Kayne's analysis is not very clear to us.